# Using a domain to test for an error thrown deep in the call stack in node.

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to write some tests that catch errors that are potentially thrown deep in a nest of callbacks and I decided to try using domains for this. I've managed to simplify to the following test case:

```
"use strict";
var assert = require("assert");
var domain = require("domain");

function wrapInDomain(throwsAnError, callback) {
    var thisDomain = domain.create();

    thisDomain.on("error", function(error) {
        console.log("calling callback");
        //thisDomain.destory(); // I'm not sure if I should do this
        callback(error);
    });

    thisDomain.run(function() {
        process.nextTick(function(){
            throwsAnError();
        });
    });
}

function throwsAnError() {
    process.nextTick(function(){
        throw new Error("I sensed a great disturbance in the force, as if millions of voices cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced. I fear something terrible has happened.");
    });
}

describe("describe something that throws an error", function(){

    it("it clause", function(done) {
        wrapInDomain(throwsAnError, function(theError) {
            console.log("got an error " + theError);
            assert(false); //Assert something
            done();
        });
    });


});
```

If the assert passes mocha gives the nice colourful summary of how many tests passed or failed. But if an assert fails, node seems to crash and drops directly. The error listed is the original rather than the failed assert.

Am I doing something very wrong here? Or is this some kind of bug that needs reporting?

```
calling callback
got an error Error: I sensed a great disturbance in the force, as if millions of voices cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced. I fear something terrible has happened.

/home/gareth2/cloud/apifacade/src/test/resources/testCase.js:23
        throw new Error("I sensed a great disturbance in the force, as if mill
              ^
Error: I sensed a great disturbance in the force, as if millions of voices cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced. I fear something terrible has happened.
    at /home/gareth2/cloud/apifacade/src/test/resources/testCase.js:23:15
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:463:13)

*node crashes*
```

I'm using the following version of node.

```
$ node --version
v0.10.33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you need to exit the domain before Mocha can trap the failing exception, because event handlers that are bound to a domain *execute in the domain*. If you change your error handler to this, it will work:

```
thisDomain.on("error", function(error) {
    thisDomain.exit();
    process.nextTick(function () {
        callback(error);
        console.log("calling callback");
    });
});
```

You need to call `process.nextTick` (or `setImmediate` or `setTimeout(..., 0)`) in the code above so that the statement `callback(error)` executes in the domain that becomes effective after `thisDomain.exit()` runs. The way Node works, when you create a new callback for handling an event or to run with `process.nextTick` (or equivalent functions), then the *callback as a whole* is associated with a specific domain. Suppose the following callback

```
myDomain.on("error", function () {
  A;
  myDomain.exit();
  B;
});
```

Any error caused by `A` will be handled in `myDomain`, but the same is true of `B` because *B belongs to the same callback as `A`*.

By using `process.nextTick`, we create a new callback which is associated with the new domain that takes effect after `thisDomain.exit()` executes. Modifying the example above, it would be:

```
myDomain.on("error", function () {
  A;
  myDomain.exit();
  process.nextTick(function () {
    B;
  });
});
```

Now `B` belongs to a different callback from `A` and this callback was created *after* we exited `myDomain` so it executes in the domain that was in effect before `myDomain` was created.

Comment: right, and I would assume `setImmediate`, or a `setTimeout` would achieve the same thing.

Comment: I was looking at the source: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/domain.js#L172

Comment: from the source it seems like the active domain is changed out without having to wait until the next tick of the event loop. At least in Node.js version 8.

Comment: thanks Louis, I actually think you might be wrong about this - check out this gist - https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/ee3d30aabda6696bf406b2ca4c52adbb

Comment: this investigation has led me to file a bug with node https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15594

Comment: so given my investigation, it does seem to be a best practice to exit the domain immediately in the domain error handler and then do any further execution in a process.nextTick handler. So you might be right after all.

Comment: The updated explanation is conceptually correct. The observable behavior is simple: when you do `myDomain.on("error", fn)`, then *conceptually* Node is associating `fn` with `myDomain`. If `myDomain.exit()` is called within `fn` *it does not change the **association** between `fn` and `myDomain`*. Yes, `process.domain` changes but changing `process.domain` does not change the *association* between `fn` and `myDomain`. It is *as if* the association was created by doing `fn.domain = myDomain`. Doing `process.domain = something` does not change the value of `fn.domain`.

Comment: I always assumed the association between fn and domain is simply the association between fn and process.domain.  When you do domain.bind(fn), it wraps the fn in a another function and slaps a try/catch around it, maybe it uses a closure to pass in the domain, but I ways though it went `catch(e){ process.domain.emit(e)}`, I need to look at the source again.

Comment: yeah, the when you call d.bind(fn), it does make d a property on the function.

Comment: When you look at the source code, you'll see Node makes the association in various ways. `domain.bind` perform the association with a closure calling `enter/exit` on the domain (https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/domain.js#L278-L283). `setTimeout` creates `Timeout` object on which it sets a `domain` field (https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/11f7dcf91ef3538e2f7e3be57ef22073ff5b9d4b/lib/timers.js#L446-L448). And the presence of a defined `domain` field on the object will cause Node to issue an `enter` on the domain before running the callback, and `exit` after the callback is done.

Comment: right but after calling `exit()` it cannot issue a `process.nextTick`? Do you happen to know if calling `d.exit()` removes all event listeners including error event listeners? From the source, it does not seem like calling exit() removes event listeners.